# Cpp: Using UTF-8 in cURL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, curl, console-application

When I get a webpage using cURL it does not seem to encode or receive the data in the correct format. Or is it that cURL gets a webpage in a standard format and the application has to uncompress/deflate/encode the output?

One of the webpages I have been trying to deal with will do for example:

- LET'S GET RIDICULOUS - Redfoo
- ROAR - Katy Perry
- WRECKING BALL â€“ Miley Cyrus
- TALK DIRTY Jason Derulo Feat. 2 Chainz

In my browser the example above displays this when set to "Western ISO-8859-1" Encoding. When on UTF-8 it works fine as a dash. The same scenario appears in my application. It works fine for every dash except this one.

Another example is the wiki UTF-8 article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

The output of the application is as below (require 10 rep to post image):
http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/7048/i23c.png

My application utilises the standard cURL copy-to-memory example with a few modifications for testing the wiki link:

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

#include <curl/curl.h>

struct MemoryStruct {
    char *memory;
    size_t size;
};


static size_t
    WriteMemoryCallback(void *contents, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
{
    size_t realsize = size * nmemb;
    struct MemoryStruct *mem = (struct MemoryStruct *)userp;

    mem->memory = (char*)realloc(mem->memory, mem->size + realsize + 1);
    if(mem->memory == NULL) {
        /* out of memory! */ 
        printf("not enough memory (realloc returned NULL)\n");
        return 0;
    }

    memcpy(&(mem->memory[mem->size]), contents, realsize);
    mem->size += realsize;
    mem->memory[mem->size] = 0;

    return realsize;
}


int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl_handle;
    CURLcode res;

    struct MemoryStruct chunk;

    chunk.memory = (char*)malloc(1);  /* will be grown as needed by the realloc above */ 
    chunk.size = 0;    /* no data at this point */ 

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    /* init the curl session */ 
    curl_handle = curl_easy_init();

    /* specify URL to get */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8");

    /* send all data to this function  */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);

    /* we pass our 'chunk' struct to the callback function */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);

    /* some servers don't like requests that are made without a user-agent
    field, so we provide one */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "libcurl-agent/1.0");

    /* get it! */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);

    /* check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));
    }
    else
    {
        char * x = chunk.memory;
        bool copyFlag = false;
        bool waitFlag = false;

        for(unsigned i = 0;i<chunk.size;i++)
        {
            if (copyFlag == true)
            {
                if (waitFlag == false)
                {
                    if (*x == '>')
                        waitFlag = true;
                }
                else if (waitFlag == true)
                {
                    if (*x == '<')
                    {
                        waitFlag = false;
                        copyFlag = false;
                        std::cout << std::endl;
                    }
                    else
                        std::cout<< *x;
                }
            }
            else if (*(x+5) == '<' && *(x+6) == '/' && *(x+7) == 'a' && *(x+8) == '>' && *(x+9) == '<' && *(x+10) == '/' && *(x+11) == 't' && *(x+12) == 'd' && *(x+13) == '>')//</a></td>
            {
                copyFlag = true;
            }
            x++;
        }
    }

    /* cleanup curl stuff */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl_handle);

    if(chunk.memory)
        free(chunk.memory);

    /* we're done with libcurl, so clean it up */ 
    curl_global_cleanup();
    system("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I can see the difference between the console and debugger that they each can only interpret certain character sets though is it possible to set this differently in cURL or should I be writing an encoding function? If so, how should I start?

Comment: cURL just receives raw bytes. It's up to you to decode those bytes into characters correctly (e.g., by setting a UTF-8 code page).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Though any idea how the combination: â€“ being that from cURL get: â - ffffffe2, € - ffffff80, “ - ffffff93. Can create a dash (-) in UTF-8?

Comment: Displaying UTF-8 (or many other encodings) correctly almost borders on an art, and definitely varies between OSes. IOW, sorry, but I can't really help much.

Comment: I may be wrong, though I think the 4 Bytes comes from the 32-bit version of my IDE (not sure why it doesn't assign the leading 3 bytes to 0). Then as for the 3 Bytes - it can apparently be made up from: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm . Don't quite understand why though as these were set in 1993 (quoting website) and I wouldn't believe they required more than 65535 ascii symbols for the use of a 3rd byte, let alone many more according to Wikipedia

Answer (score 0):

cURL returns the raw character format of the source. In this case the dash that appears in UTF-8 encoding is returned as 3 bytes, "â - ffffffe2" "€ - ffffff80, "“ - ffffff93". According to the [Unicode Index](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm) this dash is represented as "0xE2 0x80 0x94" or "e28094".

Example: Could always do a test for if the character is greater than or equal to 0xFFFF00 when page scraping and manually going through the characters.

```
    if (*x => 0xFFFFFF00)
        if (UTF_Conv(x))
        {
            //do something with the character?
            x=+2;
        }
```

followed with:

```
int UTF_Conv(char x)
{
    if ((*x == 0xffffffe2) && (*(x+1) == 0xffffffe2) && (*(x+2) == 0xffffffe2)) //dash convert
    {
        *(x+2) = '-';
        return 1;
    }

}
```

Replace the third character with a dash that that is generally tested throughout the rest of the application instead of the obscure one and increment the scraping index x to the usable dash.